A Movie About Death
The movie  is about 3, people who's lives turn upside down after a friend or relative dies, There was a girl who's friend died in a tsunami, then a British Boy who's brother was hit by a truck while being bullied, The British boy moves in with a foster family and there was 2 beds, and he was sad because of it, he eventually runs away to seek the main character who has always had a skill to talking to dead people. The man hates people that ask him for help. I think the movie was made after the 2000's. 

I can't be 100% sure as I've not watched the movie in a while but it sounds like you're describing Hereafter.
Hope this helps.
